# How can I parse the text from one countryName to another countryName in R?

Tags: r

I'm just having a really hard time figuring this out. Let's go straight to the data.

```
library(countrycode)
countries <- codelist$country.name.en  #list of countries from the library

text <- "(France) Mr. Tom(CEO) from France is getting a new car. The car is a Toyota. His wife will get a Nissan. (Spain) No information available. (Chad) Mr. Smith (from N'Djamena) bought a new house. It's very nice."
```

I'd want to create a list of the parsed text (eg. from "(France)" to "Nissan.") for all three countries. The actual text is 30 pages long and each (countryName) is followed by several paragraphs of text.

All the countryNames are in parentheses but there might be other non-country parentheses in the text or countryNames without parentheses. But the general pattern is that each segment I want to parse starts with (countryName1) and ends with (countryName2)

```
Output:
[[1]]
[1] "(France) Mr. Tom(CEO) from France is getting a new car. The car is a Toyota. His wife will get a Nissan."

[[2]]
[1] "(Spain) No information available."

[[3]]
[1] "(Chad) Mr.Smith (from N'Djamena) bought a new house. It's very nice."
```

Comment: @akrun I just noticed that. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll manually add and check each country later. But for now, I've changed it to Chad.

Comment: I meant to say if the values are different i.e. `United Kingdom` instead of `England` it may not match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the countries in the 'text' matches with the reference vector, we may `paste` the reference vector into a single string to split the string just before the country match

```
as.list(strsplit(text, sprintf('(?<=\\s)(?=(%s))', 
    paste(paste0("\\(", countries), collapse = "|")), perl = TRUE)[[1]])
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] "(France) Mr. Tom(CEO) from France is getting a new car. The car is a Toyota. His wife will get a Nissan. "

[[2]]
[1] "(Spain) No information available. "

[[3]]
[1] "(Chad) Mr. Smith (from N'Djamena) bought a new house. It's very nice."
```